# how to debug frame updating in emacs

Tags: window

I've noticed that the more frames i have open the slower any one frame becomes.  This is a big problem over an exported X session.

Ive noticed that compiling with some X-toolkits (GTK in particualar) activity in one frame will cause updating of all the other frames contents.  That is the scroll-bars in all frames flicker & occasionally it appears as though all the text in all frames is being re-rendered, there's a very slight flicker.  Eventually the rate buffers can scroll drops to a point where its silly.

So I want to debug what's going on & causing these frames to be redrawn/updated.

With a single buffer frame editing C++ code Emacs is near fluid smooth (4k screen) even with a lot of extensions running, but as I open more frames, the whole editor becomes less responsive, especially if I split some of these frames.

Comment: This question is too broad for emacs.SE, I think. As @Stefan suggested, this sounds like something to discuss on `emacs-devel@gnu.org` or in a bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: While I think it's fine to give out a couple of pointers to help out with finding the culprit, I think the best approach to this question is to close it. Since drawing the frame is done in C, you'll probably want to use some profiler for that, preferably with a build that has debug symbols in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this question will work well in an SX forum, maybe you'd be better off asking this on `emacs-devel`.  You'll probably want to investigate the toolkit part separately (e.g. try a build with Lucid toolkit or even no toolkit at all first).

For the text part, Emacs will often redisplay everything for one reason or another (e.g. a change in a face).  To help investigate those problems, you might like to take a look at the following variables `redisplay--all-windows-cause` and `redisplay--mode-lines-cause`.  They are arrays where each entry correspond to a "cause" and it contains an integer which counts how many times this cause was responsible.  You might like to look at `src/xdisp.c` while investigating this, so as to figure out what each "cause entry" corresponds to (e.g. the entry nb 50 corresponds to those places where `windows_or_buffers_changed` was assigned the value 50, the other array functions the same but with var `update_mode_lines`).